# Confusion creating swagger.json file from proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, swagger

I've created a proto file with all the necessary messages and rpc functions for a REST webservice I intend to generate. Using the protoc-gen-swagger plugin I've managed to compile that proto file into a swagger.json file and all seems well, except for two things, which I can't seem to work out.

1. All the definitions in the swagger.json file has the name of my proto file's package prefixed onto them. Is there a way to get rid of this?
2. All of the fields of my messages are "optional". They're not specified explicitly as such but they're not specified to be "required" which, by definition, makes them optional. Proto3 no longer supports required/optional/repeating but even if I use Proto2 and add those keywords, it doesn't seem to affect the swagger.json ouput. How do I specifiy in my proto file that a field is required such that protoc-gen-swagger will add the required section to the json output?

Here is a sample of a very basic proto file:

**webservice.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
package mypackage;
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service MyAPIWebService {
    rpc MyFunc (MyMessage) returns (MyResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            post: "/message"
            body: "*"
        };
    }
}

message MyMessage {
    string MyString = 1;
    int64 MyInt = 2;
}

message MyResponse {
    string MyString = 1;
}
```

This is then compiled into a swagger.json file with the following command:

> protoc -I. -I"%GOPATH%/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis" --swagger_out=logtostderr=true:. webservice.proto

which yields the following output:
**webservice.swagger.json**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "webservice.proto",
    "version": "version not set"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/message": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "MyFunc",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/mypackageMyResponse"
            }
          }
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/mypackageMyMessage"
            }
          }
        ],
        "tags": [
          "MyAPIWebService"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "mypackageMyMessage": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "MyString": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "MyInt": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "int64"
        }
      }
    },
    "mypackageMyResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "MyString": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. Notice how `MyMessage` and `MyResponse` in the proto file translates to `mypackageMyMessage` and `mypackageMyResponse` in the json file.
2. If I wanted, for instance, MyMessage:MyString to be required, I'd have to add a section to the "mypackageMyMessage" section in "definitions" that looks like this:

   "required":[
       "MyString"
   ]

I would definitely prefer if there was a way I could specify that in the proto file already so that I don't have to manually edit the json file every time I compile it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking to do something similar. Leaning towards writing a plugin that with my own options that can filter out the fields that are "Create only" or "internal".

Comment: Unfortunately no. I eventually gave up and resigned myself to a manual intervention.

Answer (score 7):

Posting here for anyone else who comes across this question looking for the same information.

---

**UPDATE** 
This is where the code defines how definitions are created.

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/protoc-gen-swagger/genswagger/template.go#L859

---

This is how you can denote fields as required -- add a custom option to your message definition:

```
message MyMessage {
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_schema) = {
        json_schema: {
            title: "MyMessage"
            description: "Does something neat"
            required: ["MyString"]
        }
    };

    string MyString = 1;
    int64 MyInt = 2;
}
```

Comment: where do you import that from?

Comment: I've tried several different imports but I cannot get access to those options in my own protos

Comment: You need to add this import:

`import "protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto";`

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/tree/master/protoc-gen-swagger

Answer (score 1):

Your prefix `mypackage` is a part of namespacing in .proto file. It is coming from line: `package mypackage;` delete this line and regenerate json